# type sql_identifier does not exis

Tags: postgresql

So I am trying to run this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TableIteration() 
  RETURNS TABLE(table_schema text, table_name text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE 
    tgt_schema varchar;
    list varchar[] := ARRAY[
    'sometext1',
    'sometext2',
    'sometext3',
    'sometext4',
    'sometext5',
    'sometext6',
    'sometext7',
    'sometext8',
    'sometext9'
];
BEGIN
    FOREACH tgt_schema IN ARRAY list
        LOOP
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
        'SELECT t.table_schema, t.table_name from information_schema.tables t'; 
        END LOOP;
    END
$$
```

And I am getting

> ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
> Detail: Returned type information_schema.sql_identifier does not match
> expected type text in column 1.

But if I change types to sql_identifier I can't create function because it says that there's no such type. So the  question is what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information schema columns have a strange data type (which - I think - is mandated by the SQL standard). Just cast them to text:

```
'SELECT t.table_schema::text, t.table_name::text from information_schema.tables t';
```

Comment: That's best. The other way to get rid of the error would be to use the return data type `information_schema.sql_identifier` (you have to include the schema name unless that schema is on your `search_path`).